# Displaying Cosine Signal in Python

Tags: python, cosine

I am new to signal processing concept, so this can be easy question.

Actually, I want to display cosine signal by using python `scipy.signal` module. The method `signal.cosine()` takes only the number of points, called also as samples. When I try to execute the code below, I get only short and one part of the cosine signal. However, I want to obtain whole, long, and periodic cosine signal. How can I do that ?

```
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

window = signal.cosine(50)
plt.plot(window)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`signal.windows.cosine` is a [window function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function), not a signal, [as it says in the docstring](http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.signal.windows.cosine.html):

> Return a window with a simple cosine shape.

You want something like `numpy.cos(2*pi*f*t)`.